# Conversion from $p$-adic to Real

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I was reading the article about $p$-adic integers from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). The algebraic approach described there seems very interesting to me.

So far I understand that if $p$ is a prime then every natural number $m$ defines a sequence $(a_n)$ by $a_n = m \bmod p^n$ and this sequence defines a $p$-adic integer. Such a sequence eventually stabilises like $(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 35, 35, 35, …)$. On the other hand an if we have a $p$-adic integer given by an ever-increasing sequence like $(1, 3, 7, 7, 23, 55, 55, 183, 439, 439, 1463 ...)$ then that corresponds to no natural number. But it might be possible that this sequence is corresponding to a real number.

So my question is

> If a prime $p$ and an ever-increasing sequence $(a_n)$ is given then is it possible to determine which real number it corresponds to?
>
> In particular if I have some formula involving $n$ and $p$ for $a_n$, say $a_n=2^n-2$ with $p=2$, then is there any way to determine/guess which real number $(a_n)$ corresponds to?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $p$-adic numbers can't be matched up to real numbers in any canonical way.

Comment: What properties of this correspondence do you insist to have? (Prepare to get disappointed.)

Comment: I am looking for any kind of approach or possible way to understand if this kind of $p$-adic integers can be realised in real, but I might be completely wrong, sorry.

Comment: The point about the $p-$adic numbers is that they have essential differences from the reals - that is why they are useful. If they were essentially the same they would be a complicated way of conveying the same information, and be mathematically redundant. They take a bit of getting used to.